# how do we determine which class an function should be contained in

Tags: c++, oop

Take a parking lot as an example. To design a parking lot which manages parking/unparking different types of cars at different types of parking slots.  We can first define a class ParkingLot, which contains parking slots, total floor, width, length of the parking lot, etc. We then define class Vehicle, which may be inherited by different vehicle type such as Car, Motercycle, etc. We can even define class Parking_Slot class...

What I am confused is in which class I should implement action functions such as park() and unpark(). It seems these functions are related to all of the three classes I mentioned: ParkingLot, Vehicle, Parking_Slot.

Can anybody explain in general in which class we should put a function if there are multiple related classes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It really depends on what you're trying to achieve, and no, this doesn't mean "it does not matter and we can put it in any of the class as long as it works" - generally there are more ways to design something badly than there are to design it well, even if the good ways and the bad ways all "work". Obviously you *can* do anything you like, if you don't care whether the solution is a good one.

For instance, if you are simulating a parking lot manager who is trying to optimize the traffic flow by deciding which vehicles go where, then clearly you wouldn't want individual vehicles making their parking decisions, or it would totally defeat the purpose of what you're trying to accomplish. Perhaps you'd have a manager object that put vehicle objects in parking slot objects in a parking lot object, or maybe you'd simplify and just have the parking lot "make the decisions". If you wanted to just simulate what passively happens in a public parking lot where drivers pick the first free space they come to, then perhaps you'd have the car object do it.

As with any other model, you're abstracting from reality, and focusing on the important elements, so you need to decide which elements these are, and what you want them to do, and design your classes accordingly. Once you figure out the best model for your particular application, then the classes will practically write themselves.

Comment: this answer is close to what I can understand.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at the [single responsibility principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle) which generally says that you should assign each class a closely related set of operations.

Try to separate out your classes into nouns and verbs(actions), so you could say:-

- Vehicle -> Park()
- ParkingSlot -> accepts(Vehicle)
- ParkingLot -> manages(Vehicles), contains(cars)

etc

Answer (score 0):

If we think about ParkingLot as a container of cars, then as is usually done, the park() function should be in the container. However this kind of thing can really change depending on how your design evolves.

Comment: both of you and manu-fatto said it depends on. Do you mean it does not matter and we can put it in any of the class as long as it works?

Answer (score 0):

OOP is all about parent-child hierarchy nad polymorphism so you can implement same functions in derived classes.

For example class ParkingLot.park() could mean to search for ANY parking spot available while when you'd need defining it more precisely you could get ParkingLot's children - ParkingSlots and choose the one most appropriate for your needs (eg a parking slot for disabled).

```
ParkingLot.parkVehicleAnywhere(const Vehicle& vehicle);
Vehicle.park(const ParkingSlot& slot);
ParkingSlot.parkVehicle(const Vehicle& vehicle);

class Motorcycle : public Vehicle;
class Car : public Vehicle;
```

You can then also use *double dispatch* to determine behaviour specific for interaction between 2 of the chosen components.

Last but not least, when settign up your hierarchy in deriving try to ask yourself a question (eg).

ParkingLot *is* a Vehicle or *has* a Vehicle?

ParkingSlot *is* a ParkingLot or *has* a Vehicle?

Motorcycle *is* a Vehicle or *has* a Vehicle?

and so forth. Asking yourself such questions can help you establish a good hierarchy of your objects.

Answer (score 0):

It is not obligatory, in C++ design, to express every action
as a method of some class.

If just a single object type is modified by the action then
you may make the action a method of that object's class. If multiple object
types X,Y[,Z..] are modified then prefer to make the action a
free function:

```
foo(X &, Y &[, Z &...]);
```

And even if only one object type `T` is modified you should still prefer
to make the operation a free function if you can implement it by means
of essential methods already belonging to `T`:

```
foo(T &, Y const &);
```

rather than:

```
T::foo(Y const &);
```

This will keep `T` free of inessential bloat and has the further
recommendation that `foo(t,y)` will work not only if `t` is actually a `T` but
also, "for free", if `t` is of a type convertible to `T` and in
particular of a type derived from `T`.